# Import react from webjars

Tags: reactjs, webjars

I have a spring project and I have added react, jquery and bootstrap webjars in  my project. I want to use them in react as import statements.

My pom Dependency:

```
 `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>react</artifactId>
    <version>15.3.2</version>
</dependency>`
```

I want to know how to use react and jquery in my react project .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I include react and jquery in my Maven project:

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
        <artifactId>react-dom</artifactId>
        <version>15.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**In webpage I refer to the libraries as follows:**

```
<script src="webjars/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/react-dom/15.6.1/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Intellij IDEA will help you getting the path's right. Note that you may have to force a Maven reload libraries if autocompletion does not work...

Also note that react and react-dom separated into two different webjars somewhere between 15.0.1 and 15.6.1. In 15.0.1 both react and react-dom is in the same library.

Best regards from Ove